# Store reference to a string in a list

Tags: python, string, object, weak-references

The following code prints "original value". I want to store a reference to a string in the list, so that the string stored in the list and first_string always point to the same object. How can I do it in python? I want to store a reference, preferably a weak one in a list. The list should be a list of references to objects of different types. I'm just testing how to do different things in python and what's possible. Is it something that can be achieved in python?

```
my_list = []

first_string = 'original value'
my_list.append(first_string)

first_string = 'changed'

print(my_list[0])
```

It should print "changed".

...

I tried getting a weak reference to the string using:

```
weakref.ref(first_string)
```

but apparently it's not possible to get a weak reference to a string object.

```
cannot create weak reference to 'str' object
```

Despite that storing id is a bad idea (because an object can be CG and the id then can point to a different one) I still tried it:

```
import ctypes
my_list = []

first_string = 'original value'
my_list.append(id(first_string))

ctypes.cast(my_list[0], ctypes.py_object).value = 'changed value'

print(first_string)
```

And it also didn't work. The printed value was still the original. So is it something that can't be done in python?

Comment: Why do you need it for? Strings in Python are immutable, so they cannot be changed (but other string can be bound to the same name). If you need data structure to hold different strings, use structure like dictionary or make this string property of class (and keep objects in list).

Comment: Indeed, the immutability of strings is something that gets a lot of newcomers to python.

Comment: [Bytearrays](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) are mutable, FWIW. Since a byte array can hold, well, bytes, it can hold any ASCII string. (Therefore it's entirely compatible with the Python *2* string object, but not Python 3's, which are multibyte.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do in python can only work with *mutable* types. If two 'labels' refer to the same mutable object, you can perform actions on one label and it will be reflected when accessing the other since it is the same object. In short, wrap it in a list or class --

```
>>> class PyString:
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.string = string
>>> first_string = PyString("original_value")
>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list.append(first_string)
>>> first_string.string = "changed"
>>> my_list[0].string
'changed'
```